# WGet зависает после подключения

Tags: консоль, wget

Есть **txt** файл со списком **URL**. Скачиваю их командой

> wget --tries=3 wget --dns-timeout=30 wget --timeout=30 wget -P D:\Projects\Wbot\soft\datasets\metal_cans wget -i
>    D:\Projects\Wbot\soft\datasets\metal_cans.txt

В первой части этой команды ставлю ограничения на ожидание в пятнадцать секунд. Но иногда всё равно возникаем проблема, когда утилита, успешно подключившись к серверу, зависает. Точнее, я так полагаю, она ждёт получения картинки с сервера, а он не отправляет. Вот так вот уже час. Соединение установилось и дальше ничего Что делать в таком случае?

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 0):

В выводе чётко сказано: необходим правильный сертификат. Если желаете без проверки серта: используйте соответствующий параметр (приводится). Т.е запустите скачивание без проверки серта и посмотрите, что будет